# Can't connect to xdebug in PHPStorm

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, phpstorm, xdebug

### The problem

So I feel although I've tried everything and still can't get xdebug to connect to phpstorm. I says it waiting for a connection, then when I load the page, using either the get variable `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` or the chrome extension, the message briefly changes to `connected`, before going back to waiting.
The error:[image: PHPStorm error]

In the error log at `E:\xampp\apache\logs\xdebug.log` is as follows

```
Log opened at 2016-03-29 16:35:40
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 12hitchinscouts.local:9001.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///E:/Users/Roshan/PhpstormProjects/12hitchinscouts.org.uk/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="4396" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.2.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2014 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- status -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="5" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t line -f file://E:/Users/Roshan/PhpstormProjects/12hitchinscouts.org.uk/index.php -n 8
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6"><error code="5"><message><![CDATA[command is not available]]></message></error></response>

Log closed at 2016-03-29 16:35:41
```

### My current config

I'm using Apache 2.4 on Windows 7 Pro with xampp and php5.6

php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "E:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "E:\xampp\tmp\xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "12hitchinscouts.local"
xdebug.remote_port= 9001
xdebug.remote_log= "E:\xampp\apache\logs\xdebug.log"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "E:\xampp\tmp\xdebug"
xdebug.extended_info  = 1
```

phpinfo

[image: phpinfo]

[image: phpinfo]

PHPStorm

[image: PHP debug settings]

[image: PHP server settings]

[image: Debug setting]

[image]

### What I've tried

- Using break-points in PHPStorm
- Using `xdebug_break();` in PHPStorm
- Setting remote host to this `xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"` in php.ini
- Various tutorials and forum posts to get me to this point

If you need any more info then feel free to ask, but I *think* I've provided it all.

Thanks

Whooo, you reached the bottom :)

### Edit

Here's my php file:

```
<?php
//set page title
$title = "Welcome";
//for Facebook and twitter
$metaTitle = 'Looking to join Scouting or find out about our group?'; //title for post
$metaImage = 'http://12hitchinscouts.org.uk/images/FB-img.JPG'; //image url for post
$metaDesc = 'This is the official website for the 12th Hitchin scout group. Here you can find out about our different sections; when and where they meet as well as what they\'ll be doing next. This group consists of beavers cubs and scouts sections.'; //description to appear on post
$headMeta = '<!--for extra google results page features and SEO-->
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
       "@context": "http://schema.org",
       "@type": "Organization",
       "url": "https://12hitchinscouts.org.uk/",
       "logo": "http://12hitchinscouts.org.uk/images/12th-Logo.png",
       "name" : "12th Hitchin Scouts",
       "sameAs" : [ "http://www.facebook.com/groups/12hitchinscouts/",
        "http://www.twitter.com/12thhs" ],
       "potentialAction": {
         "@type": "SearchAction",
         "target": "https://12hitchinscouts.org.uk/search#stq={search_term_string}",
         "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
       }
    }
    </script>
    <meta name="Description" content="This is the homepage for the 12th Hitchin scouts, from here you can find out what\'s going on and see upcoming activities for each section of our Hitchin scout group. Hitchin is our home too, and that\'s why we are commited to helping our local area aswell as other usual scouting activities.">'; //schema info for google
xdebug_break();
require("includes/head.php");
?>
<link href="css/index_response.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--content-->
  <div class="fluid Title"><h1>Welcome!</h1></div>
    <br />
    <div class="fluid twitter hide_mobile ">
        <h2>Tweets
            <span class="follow">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/12thhs" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/Twitter_logo.gif" />
                Follow
                </a>
            </span>
        </h2>
        <br />
        <span class="tweets">
        <?php include_once("includes/twitter.php"); ?>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="fluid what">
        <h2>What is scouting?</h2>
        <p>Scouts was invented in 1907 by Robert Baden-Powell with just 20 boys. Over
a century later the number is into millions worldwide. There are many
stories around scouting, which could take up this entire pack – but suffice to
say it has evolved over the last century in many different ways.
We aim to ensure that a balanced programme is achieved which allows the
children to grow mentally, physically, socially and spiritually. Scouts
nowadays still need to Be Prepared as the old motto goes, and we have
many activities that are fun, testing and hopefully, a little bit out of the
ordinary – offering something new and different to everyone. We have tried
many activities over the last few years ranging from Bowling and archery to
bouldering and kayaking. We have walked in the peak district camping
overnight, conversely, we have walked for a couple of hours around
Deacon’s hill in Hitchin.</p>
<p>All the scout basics are there, including hiking, camping, first aid and
numerous badges catering from hobbies and activities to in depth levelled
badges for swimming or aeronautics! We also aim to complete a Challenge
Badge every 1-2 terms, which when collected gains the Chief Scouts Gold
award – the highest accolade available as a Scout. To earn this, Scouts show
their creativity, outdoor skills, help the community, learn about faiths and
tolerance and ultimately – go on an expedition for a few days, planned and
carried out by themselves!</p>
<p>Joining the scouts will leave you in esteemed company as people such as
Kate Middleton, Major Tim Peake, David Beckham, Nelson Mandela, Barack Obama, Richard
Branson, Ross Kemp and our current Chief Scout Bear Grylls, have all been
involved in scouting.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fluid index_events">
        <h2>Upcoming events</h2>
        <?php 
        $no = 1; //number of upcoming events to display, 0 or less shows 1. Non integers are rounded and values of 0 or less are turned to 1
        $index = 1; //this is the index page, leave blank for implementation on other pages. uses if($index == 1) logic
        $limit['years'] = 1;//how far into the future should it show events? Non integers are rounded and values of 0 or less are turned to 1
        //This shows events from all sections, to specify a section, a line must be added the SQL queries
        include("includes/upcoming_events.php");
        ?>
    </div>    
    <div class="fluid galery">
        <h2>Gallery</h2><p><a href="/gallery">Visit full gallery</a></p>
        <?php require("includes/gallery_embed.php"); ?>
   </div>
<!--end content-->
    <?php require("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

I know I spelt `gallery` wrong, I just haven't gotten around to fixing it yet :)

### Edit 2

xdebug log

```
Log opened at 2016-03-29 18:21:04
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9001.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///E:/Users/Roshan/PhpstormProjects/12hitchinscouts.org.uk/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="11672" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.2.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2014 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- status -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="5" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t line -f file://E:/Users/Roshan/PhpstormProjects/12hitchinscouts.org.uk/index.php -n 3
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6"><error code="5"><message><![CDATA[command is not available]]></message></error></response>

Log closed at 2016-03-29 18:21:05
```

PHPStorm log

It was too long to post [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8sGYjbjc)

Comment: 1) It's xdebug who connects to PhpStorm and NOT other way around; 2) Try updating your xdebug -- use v2.3.2 (2.3.3 has some issues in some cases; leave 2.4 for PHP 7 for now); 3) It' possible that you are using some wrong/different xdebug build -- the xdebug should be listed on your first screenshot (just under "Zend Engine 2.6" line). 4) Basically, xdebug connects to IDE and PhpStorm issues "set breakpoint" command but xdebug responds with "cannot do that" -- would be good to see the file as well (screenshot should do fine)

Comment: 5) Disable xdebug profiler for now -- `xdebug.profiler_enable = 0`; If you need to use it -- set `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1` and then trigger it on/off when needed via cookie or browser extension (having profiler with actual debug session makes little sense -- all figures will be wrong: either debug or profile code -- one at a time).

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: does your DNS resolve the `12hitchinscouts.local` name to an IP address (especially true of the box that is running php). It does not matter that that would be the same box as the one running PhpStorm, the key is , does the DNS resolve it ?

Comment: The page loads if that's what you mean, otherwise I'm not sure how to test local DNS resolution

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra on the box running php, open a terminal and type `ping 12hitchinscouts.local`, if DNS resolves the name, the pings will echo an address. Caveat : abysmally ignorant of windows i am, so the actual way to do this is yours to find :)

Comment: yep, it returned ::1: (IPv6 localhost)

Comment: well, the only other guess coming to mind would be that some process is already hogging port 9001 on your puter. Try changing the port. If you change `php.ini` and are using `php-fpm` dont forget to kill all `php-fpm` processes and restart them.

Comment: OK, let's try this: 1) `xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"` (it has to be IPv4) 2) In your `PHP | Servers` -- Host field -- it has to be domain name only -- remove protocol (although it should not be a problem here) 3) Place breakpoint on simple line (e.g. line #3 where whole command is on one line) instead of command that takes multiple lines (xdebug cannot always stop at such lines) 4) Provide new xdebug log for such debug attempt 5) collect logs from PhpStorm side: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs

Comment: Ok, I've done all of that and it didn't seem to help. I've updated the post with the info.

Comment: 1) I still see that you are using xdebug 2.2.5;  2) It's xdebug that breaks the connection -- it's clearly shown in both logs (in xdebug logs #1 and #2 + PhpStorm log); Update xdebug and provide new xdebug log (as well as head of phpinfo() output -- same as  screenshot #1).

Comment: hmm, I have changed this line in php.ini and restarted the server. I don't know why the xdebug version hasn't changed. `zend_extension = "E:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.6-vc11-nts.dll"`

Comment: I renamed the original file (to make sure it wouldn't load) and now, the script hit a fatal error, where else would it call the xdebug extension from? I can confirm I'm editing the php.ini file named in `phpinfo()`

Comment: If you are using XAMPP ... which means Apache ... then why are you trying to use `nts` build (which is used by IIS and other configs)? Apache handler should use `thread safe` builds of xdebug (or any other extension).

Comment: https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.6-vc11.dll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107662/discussion-between-roshan-bhumbra-and-lazyone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @LazyOne in the comments I needed to update my xdebug version to [2.3.2](https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.6-vc11.dll)

*LazyOne didn't post an answer so I'm doing it, if they do, I'll accept theirs.*

Answer (score 0):

Try with these settings, and download [this](https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.4.0-7.0-vc14.dll) dll file. It works fine for me:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "E:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Comment: This actually made it worse, it doesn't even show connecting for a brief period anymore. I've reverted it.