# Xdebug PhpStorm : Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 4

Tags: phpstorm

I searched online and followed all of them. It still didn't work. xdebug works on a script file but does not work on web application and `xdebug.log` is empty.

[image: my php.ini file:]

```
phpinfor():
xdebug support       enabled
version              2.2.3
ide key              11047
```

I started listening for PHP debug connections.

[image: debug session example here.]

It worked before I setup XDEBUG_SESSION_START.

Here is my xdebug.log file:

```
Log opened at 2016-03-30 19:13:03
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9001.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///root/marketriders/public/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="4476" idekey="17624"><engine version="2.2.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2013 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- status -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="5" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t line -f file:///root/marketriders/public/index.php -n 30
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6"><error code="5"><message><![CDATA[command is not available]]></message></error></response>

Log closed at 2016-03-30 19:13:03
```

Any suggestion and comments are appreciated.

Comment: 1) Better upgrade to xdebug v2.3.2  2) Please provide xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session

Comment: I tried xdebug v2.4 dev, it had same issue. xdebug.log is empty.

Comment: make certain that the process running php has write privilege on the `xdebug.log` file ... lack thereof has given me some odd behaviours in the past.

Comment: I debugged same file as a script. it worked. here is a part of log file: Log opened at 2016-03-30 15:00:51
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" 

<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="

Comment: The user context may be different ... you as a system user:group may have write access, but maybe the apache(?) process is started automagically under a user:group which have not. I got bitten by that early in my xdebug days ;)

Comment: yes. you are right. I changed it to 777 and added log into my original post.

Comment: are you sure your idekey match (php.ini and PhpStorm) ?

Comment: they don't match. could you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the log. As it's clearly stated in the log -- xdebug successfully connects to IDE but then drops connection. Reason -- your xdebug is too old for this PhpStorm version -- please upgrade to **xdebug v2.3.2** (leave v2.4 for PHP 7). Same as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36293690/783119

Comment: If still nothing -- post your `phpinfo()` output grabbed via browser (and not console).

Answer (score 1):

By default, PHPStorm assumes the debug session will be on port 9000.  According to your php.ini file, you have configured xdebug to run on port 9001.  In PHPStorm, go to Settings > Langauge&Frameworks > PHP > Debug and make sure the "Debug port" matches your php.ini port setting of 9001.

Answer (score 0):

solved. there is an extra line "extention=/path to/xdebug.so" in php.ini. after removed this line. it worked well.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There no this line 'extention=/path'  in php.ini, I can't find this line.